# Prove a serie convergent: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n + (2an)^2}{1+n^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the following convergent for every $A \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n + (2An)^2}{1+n^4} < \infty
$$

I've tried all the tests I know, they all fail.

Comment: Which tests have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By limit comparison test, we can take $a_n=\dfrac{2n+(2An)^2}{1+n^4}$ and $b_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. Thus, we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{2n+(2An)^2}{1+n^4}}{\dfrac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2n^3+4A^2n^4}{1+n^4}=4A^2.
\end{align*}

If $A\neq 0$, then the limit exists and is different from zero, and since $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}}$ converges, so does $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2n+(2An)^2}{1+n^4}}$.

Using a similar method for $A=0$, you will find that the series converges for all $A\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Tried the comparison test, didn't think about the *limit* comparison test. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, the limit comparison test is much more useful when it comes to quotients of polynomials, and it is really easy to guess the appropriate sequence to compare with.